# what's the difference between an HTTP Request and consuming data from an API, is there any?

Tags: api, httprequest

I'm always doing CRUD operations tu URLS, I kind of think they are HTTP requests. Are http request a way of comsuming an API?

For example, In the main page of jsonPlaceholder.typicode.com, they have this GET example:

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json))
```

What term best describe this operation?

a) An HTTP request
b) the consumption of the jsonPlaceHolder API

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, and DELETE are all HTTP methods